# Vuejs Nested Loop 3 levels SubMenu

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, object

Link for demo https://jsfiddle.net/Hani_Gerges/bzec0sgu/18/
i have an object like this

```
{
   "Master Records":{
      "null":[
         {
            "level1Title":"Master Records",
            "level2Title":null,
            "title":"Departments",
            "pageUrl":"/Departments/DepartmentsList",
            "description":null,
            "roles":null
         }
      ]
   },
   "Legal":{
      "null":[
         {
            "level1Title":"Legal",
            "level2Title":null,
            "title":"Law Offices",
            "pageUrl":null,
            "description":null,
            "roles":null
         }
      ]
   },
   "Social Media":{
      "null":[
         {
            "level1Title":"Social Media",
            "level2Title":null,
            "title":"Twitter",
            "pageUrl":"https://twitter.com",
            "description":"Twitter",
            "roles":null
         },
         {
            "level1Title":"Social Media",
            "level2Title":null,
            "title":"Facebook",
            "pageUrl":"https://facebook.com",
            "description":null,
            "roles":null
         }
      ]
   },
   "null":{
      "null":[
         {
            "level1Title":null,
            "level2Title":null,
            "title":"Contact Us",
            "pageUrl":"/ContactUs/ContactUs",
            "description":"Contact Us",
            "roles":null
         },
         {
            "level1Title":null,
            "level2Title":null,
            "title":"About Us",
            "pageUrl":"/AboutUs",
            "description":null,
            "roles":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and i am trying to loop in it to get the right menu

and this is my code

```
 <div class="navbar-content scroll-div">
            <ul class="nav pcoded-inner-navbar">
                <li class="nav-item pcoded-hasmenu">
                    <template v-for="(level1Title, Key) in level1Items" :Key="Key" v-if="Key !='null'">
                        <a class="nav-link "><span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="mdi mdi-contacts"></i></span><span class="pcoded-mtext">{{Key}}</span></a>
                        <ul class="pcoded-submenu">
                            <li class="pcoded-hasmenu" v-for="(level2Title, Key) in level1Title" :Key="Key" v-if="Key !='null'">
                                <a class="">
                                    <span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="mdi mdi-contacts"></i></span>
                                    <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{Key}}</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="pcoded-submenu">
                                    <li class="" v-for="(title, Key) in level2Title" :Key="Key" v-show="On">
                                        <a :href="title.pageUrl" class="">
                                            <span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="mdi mdi-contacts"></i></span>
                                            <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{title.title}}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item active pcoded-trigger" v-for="(level1Title, Key) in level1Items" :Key="Key" v-if="Key !='null'">
                                <ul class="nav pcoded-inner-navbar" v-for="(level2Title, Key) in level1Title" :Key="Key" v-if="Key =='null'">
                                    <li class="nav pcoded-inner-navbar" v-for="(title, Key) in level2Title" :Key="Key">
                                        <a :href="title.pageUrl" class="nav-link">
                                            <span class="pcoded-micon"><i v-bind:class=IconName></i></span>
                                            <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{title.title}}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </template>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav pcoded-inner-navbar">
                <li class="nav-item active pcoded-trigger" v-for="(level1Title, Key) in level1Items" :Key="Key" v-if="Key =='null'">
                    <ul class="nav pcoded-inner-navbar" v-for="(level2Title, Key) in level1Title" :Key="Key" v-if="Key =='null'">
                        <li class="nav pcoded-inner-navbar" v-for="(title, Key) in level2Title" :Key="Key">
                            <a :href="title.pageUrl" class="nav-link">
                                <span class="pcoded-micon"><i v-bind:class=IconName></i></span>
                                <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{title.title}}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

my problem is when level2 title is not found it duplicate all items in every menu
like if i openned 1st item in the menu i found all titles in it even it only has 1 title in it,

i have 2 separate UL to get the level3 items which has no level 1 or 2
and the onther ul to get level 1 => level 2 ( if not null ) => level 3

like this screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQCNT.png)

Comment: please have this reproduced in a fiddle.

Comment: @Himanshu https://jsfiddle.net/Hani_Gerges/bzec0sgu/9/

Comment: I think codesandboxes are better for vue applications (if you're doing the compiled version), but you also need to clean up your code and format it better. It's way too hard to read.

Comment: please check this https://jsfiddle.net/Hani_Gerges/bzec0sgu/18/
i have re design it by colors
red for level 1
blue for level 2
green for level 3
consider that i have no level 2 for now